# Three-of-a-kind Poker Hand Problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, poker

Problem:

- Three-of-a-kind poker hand: Three cards have one rank and the remaining two cards have
  two other ranks. e.g. {2♥, 2♠, 2♣, 5♣, K♦}

Calculate the probability of drawing this kind of poker hand.

My confusion: When choosing the three ranks, the explanation used $13 \choose 1$ and $12 \choose 2$. I used $13 \choose 3$ instead which ends up being wrong. I do not know why.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/132367/960197

Comment: Select the rank of he three of a kind: you choose **one** rank from thirteen possibilities. The pick the ranks of the remaining two cards, which must be different from each other and from the rank you chose already. These two play symmetric roles, because it does not matter which one goes first. Your choice of $\binom{13}{3}$ treats the ranks of the three of a kind and the remaining two cards as playing symmetric roles, which they do not, because you need to treat the rank of the three of a kind differently from how you treat the other two ranks.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But the orders of the 3 ranks does not matter. In the example above cards of rank 2 need not come first. I could have 5♣, K♦, 2♥, 2♠, 2♣.

Comment: After you pick the three ranks, how do you decide which one is the three of a kind? After deciding it will be 5, king, and 2, how do you know if it will be three 2s, a five, and a king: or three 5s, a king, and a 2: or three kings, a 5, and a 2? That's why the order of the ranks matter: or rather, you need to single put **one** rank: for the other two the order does not matter.

Comment: We are not talking about the order in which you list them in your hand, but how you describe the finished hand. Again, you first pick one rank, which will be the rank if the three-of-a-kind. That's $\binom{13}{1}$. Then we pick the two ranks of the singleton, $\binom{12}{2}$. Then we pick the suits of the three-of-a-kind, then the suits of the remaining two cards. Thatks the description of the cards that constitute the hand, not the order in which you list them.

Comment: (Alternatively, after choosing the three ranks in $\binom{13}{3}$ ways, you need to pick one to be the three-of-a-kind. There are $3$ choices, so total is $3\binom{13}{3}$. But that is exactly the same as $\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{2}$. So if you calculate correctly, you get the same count.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mistake is made so often by beginners, that I advise that you consider it as reserving bags for chosen ranks from $13$ bags.

So one bag needs to be reserved for the triple, and two for the two singles, hence $\binom{13}1\binom{12}2$.

The order in which we reserve does not matter, so we could as well write $\binom{13}2\binom{11}1$, although the first, of course, will seem the more natural.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, we can use $\binom{13}{3}$: it counts the number of ways of choosing 3 distinct ranks.  Just don't forget to also choose which of those three ranks (i.e., $\binom{3}{1}$) is the special rank with 3 cards.  It's another way of counting the same thing:  $$\binom{13}{3} \binom{3}{1} = \frac{13!}{3!\ 10!} \times 3 = 13 \times \frac{12!}{2!\ 10!} = \binom{13}{1} \binom{12}{2}.$$

Afterwards, we also need to choose suits (hearts, diamonds, clubs, spades) for each rank.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to solve it through unordered samples.

We are looking for hands of the kind $x_1$-$x_2$-$x_2$-$y$-$z$, where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are all of the same face value (although of a different suit), whereas $y,z$ are different face values.

To work with unordered hands, let's fix the order of the cards as above, i.e. three of a kind are the first three cards followed by two other different kinds.

There are 13 possible face values (2, 3, $\ldots$, K, A), and for each face value, there are ${4\choose 3}$ ways to select 3 cards out of 4, disregarding order and without replacement. This fills $x_1$-$x_2$-$x_3$.

For $y$, there are 48 possibilities, since three face values have already been drawn and the one left cannot be used. For $z$, there are 44 possibilities since the other three remaining cards of the face values chosen in $y$ cannot be either.

However, we are not done yet, i.e. $13{4\choose 3}48\cdot44$ is not quite right because this number includes also poker hands s.t. 4s-4c-4h-2s-3h and 4s-4c-4h-3h-2s, which are obviously indistinguishable since order doesn't matter. But the last two cards can be ordered in 2! ways. Dividing by $2!$, we remove those hands that differ only in the ordering in the last two cards.

The right number of poker hands with a three-of-a-kind is thus

$$13{4\choose 3}\frac{48\cdot44}{2!},$$

and the required probability is

$$
\frac{13 {4\choose 3}\frac{48\cdot44}{2!}}{{52 \choose 5}}.
$$